# Read inputstream of a java process

Tags: java, process, io, inputstream, processbuilder

I am trying to run a Linux process using the Processbuilder in java and then read the input and error streams. The Linux process is a blocking one and writes output to console/stdout.

When I try to read the input stream (error stream redirected) of the java process, I get no data until the process writes up to 4K bytes. Once process output reaches around this limit, I get the data available in input stream. How to change this behavior and get the data in real time from the input stream instead of waiting until it reaches 4K.

Here is what I tried:

```
process = new ProcessBuilder().command("some daemon program", "arg1").start();

InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

String line = null;

while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)

   System.out.println(line);
```

I get data available in input stream only after ~4k bytes. Any ideas???

Answer (score 0):

That's buffering in the producing process. There's nothing you can do about it at the Java end.

Comment: The same c program when run in command line interface, it outputs immediately even for as less as 100 bytes as well. But when ran using java, the problem arises.

Comment: No. When run with its output to a pipe instead of the console, stdio line buffering no longer happens. Java has nothing to do with it.